# Write a program with three functions, call the first function from main

Tags: c

a.    In the first function print “Hello, I’m in function 1”.  Call the second function.

b.    In the second function ask the user to enter a float value.  Call a third function and pass the value to it.

c.    In the third function calculate the square root of the number.  Return the square root to the second function, then the first function and then to main.

d.    Print the square root in main in TWO decimal places.

Please correct my coding for since I'm not getting the desired output.

```c
float a(float);
void b(float);
void c(float);
void main(float d)
{
  printf("In main\n");
  printf("back in main \n");
  printf("The square root is %f", d);
}

float a(float c)
{
  printf("Hello,I'm in function 1");
  return (c);
}

void b(float b)
{
  float number;
  printf("in function 2");
  printf("enter a float value");
  scanf("%f", &number);
  c(number);
  return a(number);
}

void c(float a)
{
  float power;
  printf("in function 3");
  power = sqrt(a);
  return b(power);
}
```

Comment: "Hello,I'm" lacks a blank. If that is not the mistake which fails your output to match the required one, then please explain what difference you need to get rid of.

Comment: What have you done so far to debug your program? (@yunnosch whoops, using my phone 2am, got the answer box mixed up with the comment box!)

Comment: b calls c, c calls b. Your are not yet at recursion, are you? Return to second function means reurning without calling b. Declare the return type correctly, float instead of void. Same again elsewhere. You seem to need to reread the textbook chapters on calling functions, returning values from functions and using the returned values in the calling function. Explaining all that here would amount to a tutorial. Your question is hence too broad.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use a title for your question that specifies your problem. A plain jomework assignment is not sufficiently specific.

Answer (score 2):

1. **What libraries have you included?** stdio.h is required for printf function and math.h is also required to implement the sqrt() function.

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
```

2. **Your functions are incorrectly defined:**

   - a requires no input and returns no data so it should be void
   - b returns float variable so it should be labelled as such.
   - c has type float for input as well as output

```c
    void a(void);
    float b(void);
    float c(float);
```

3. **printf is not the way to call your functions.** 
   You simply type the name of the function and arguments if you have any into your main function in the order you wish to call them.

**example:**

```
void main()
{
    //declare your variable
    float num;

    //calls a function
    a();

    //calls b function and initializes num as value returned from b
    num = b();

    //calls c function and passes variable num to parameter in c function
    c(num);
}
```

This should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: Hello and welcome, this is a helpful answer. I just wanted to let you know that `stdio.h` is technically not always required but in this case necessary for `printf`. Maybe you could mention that in your answer to improve it a bit. Also your point 3 is strangly indented.

Comment: Thanks Kami, good point. I noticed that indentation as well but for the life of me I could not fix it. 

Comment: Have a look at the suggested edit. Maybe this can help you and if it okay you can just approve it and afterwards you might want to edit the clarification for stdio.h in the question (see the edit link below your answer)

Comment: `void a();` is obsolete style, don't teach that to newbies. The correct form is `void a(void);`

Comment: Done and done KK. Lundin, I was unaware as I am not exactly a veteran myself. Feel free to make the edit and I will approve.

Comment: If Lundin would edit your answer, you can not approve it as he has over 2k reputation. Also you should take care of your answer yourself. So please edit it yourself.

Comment: I have edited it to show that style, would one of you be so kind as to explain why this is the proper form?